# Which sequence of functions converges uniformly

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, uniform-convergence

I want to check which of the following sequences of functions converges uniformly.

1. $\sin (x^n), \ x\in\left[\frac{1}{2}, 1\right ]$
2. $\sin (x^{\frac{1}{n}}), \ x\in\left[0, \frac{1}{2}\right ]$
3. $\sin (x^{\frac{1}{n}}), \ x\in\left[\frac{1}{2}, 1\right ]$
4. $\sin (x^n), \ x\in\left[0,\frac{1}{2}\right ]$

I have done the following :

First we check the pointwise convergence, so we consider the limit as $n\rightarrow \infty$.

We have the following:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sin (x^n)=0 \text{ for both intervals of } x $$
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sin (x^{\frac{1}{n}})= \sin (1) \text{ for both intervals of } x$$

Then we have to consider the functions $g_1(x)=|\sin (x^n)-0|=|\sin (x^n)|$ and $g_2(x)=|\sin (x^{\frac{1}{n}})-\sin (1)|$ and to check if the minimum goes to $0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$, right?

For that need the derivatives of these two functions, or not?

We have $g_1'(x)=|nx^{n-1}\cos (x^n)|$ and $g_2'(x)=|\frac{1}{n}x^{\frac{1}{n}-1}\cos (x^{\frac{1}{n}}))|$.

Then we need the roots of the first derivative, right?

Or do we have to do that in an other way?

Comment: $0^{\frac{1}{n}}=0$ whatever the value of $n$ is.

Comment: Where do we need this? @mathcounterexamples.net

Comment: Be careful with your first statement about $\sin (x^n)$. What about $x=1$?

Comment: Ahh yes!So $\sin (x^n)$ doesn't converge pointwise in $\left [\frac{1}{2},1\right ]$,right? @mathcounterexamples.net

Comment: And $\sin (x^{\frac{1}{n}})$ doesn't converge pointwise in $\left [0,\frac{1}{2}\right ]$.Is that correct? @mathcounterexamples.net

Comment: @MaryStar Correct and correct.

Comment: Sosince we don;t have pointwise convegence we don'thave also uniform. So we consider also $\sin (x^n)$ in $\left [0,\frac{1}{2}\right ]$ and $\sin (x^{\frac{1}{n}})$ in $\left [\frac{1}{2},1\right ]$. Is the next step for these ones the part with the function $g$ I wrote above, correct? @mathcounterexamples.net

Comment: Well, I might be wrong but I think we do have pointwise convergence, but to a non-continuous function on $[\frac{1}{2},1].$ Since each of the $\sin (x^n)$ functions are continuous, the convergence isn’t uniform.

Comment: Do you mean that because the function of pointwise continuity is not continuous we don't have uniform convergence? @Jujustum

Comment: If $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of continuous functions that converges uniformly to $f$, then $f$ must be continuous.

Comment: By this argument the sequences (1) and (4) don't converge uniformly, right? @Jujustum

Comment: Only for sequence (1), because $f$ is continuous on $[0,\frac{1}{2}]$.

Comment: Thank you!! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f_n(x)=\sin(x^n)$ and $g_n(x)=\sin(x^{\frac{1}{n}})$.

We will also use:
$$f(x)=\left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
      0 \text{ if } x\in [0,1[ \\
      \sin (1) \text{ if } x=1 \\
\end{array} \right.$$
$$g(x)=\left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
      0 \text{ if } x=0 \\
      \sin (1) \text{ if } x \in ]0,1] \\
\end{array} \right.$$

**Pointwise convergence**

Let $x \in [0,1[$. Then, $\underset{n \rightarrow +\infty}{\lim} f_n(x)=\sin(0)=0$, because $\sin$ is continuous. For $x=1$, we have $\underset{n \rightarrow +\infty}{\lim} f_n(1)=\underset{n \rightarrow +\infty}{\lim} \sin(1)=\sin(1)$. Therefore, $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges to $f$ on $[0,1]$.

Let $x \in ]0,1]$. Then, $\underset{n \rightarrow +\infty}{\lim} g_n(x)=\sin(1)$. For $x=0$, $\underset{n \rightarrow +\infty}{\lim} g_n(0)=\underset{n \rightarrow +\infty}{\lim} 0=0$. So, $(g_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}^*}$ converges to $g$ on $[0,1]$.

**Uniform convergence**

1. For all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $f_n$ is continuous on $[\frac{1}{2},1].$ Since $f$ isn't continuous at $1$, we can conclude that $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ doesn't converge uniformly to $f$ on $[\frac{1}{2},1]$.
2. For all $n \in \mathbb{N}^*$, $g_n$ is continuous on $[0,\frac{1}{2}].$ Since $g$ isn't continuous at $0$, we can conclude that $(g_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}^*}$ doesn't converge uniformly to $g$ on $[0,\frac{1}{2}]$.
3. $\forall x \in [\frac{1}{2},1], |g_n(x)-g(x)|=|\sin(x^{\frac{1}{n}})-\sin(1)| \leq |\sin(\frac{1}{2}^{\frac{1}{n}})-\sin(1)| \underset{n \rightarrow +\infty} {\rightarrow} 0$. Consequently, $\underset{n \rightarrow +\infty}{\lim} \underset{x \in [\frac{1}{2},1]}{\sup} |g_n(x)-g(x)|=0$ and $(g_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}^*}$ converges uniformly to $g$ on $[\frac{1}{2},1]$.
4. $\forall x \in [0,\frac{1}{2}], |f_n(x)-f(x)|=|\sin(x^n)-0| \leq |\sin(\frac{1}{2}^n)| \underset{n \rightarrow +\infty} {\rightarrow} 0$. Consequently, $\underset{n \rightarrow +\infty}{\lim} \underset{x \in [0,\frac{1}{2}]}{\sup} |f_n(x)-f(x)|=0$ and $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges uniformly to $f$ on $[0,\frac{1}{2}]$.

Hope it helps.

Comment: At (3) do we not have $$|\sin(x^{\frac{1}{n}})-\sin(1)| \leq |\sin(1^{\frac{1}{n}})-\sin(1)|$$ since $x\in \left[\frac{1}{2},1\right ]$ ?

Comment: $|\sin(x^{\frac{1}{n}})-\sin(1)|=\sin(1)-\sin(x^{\frac{1}{n}}) \leq \sin(1)-\sin(\frac{1}{2}^{\frac{1}{n}})$ since $\sin$ is strictly increasing on $[\frac{1}{2},1]$. You actually wrote $|\sin(x^{\frac{1}{n}})-\sin(1)| \leq 0$ (which is obviously wrong)

Comment: Ahh I got it now!! Thank you very much!! :-)